# How to split pdf file into different pages

Tags: pdf

I have a document with extension **.pdf** . But it is secured one. If it is converted into unsecured(normal) mode ,  4 pages is converted. So i think if it is splited into several pages, I can get whole pages with unsecured(normal) mode. So please help me to **split pdf file into different pages**.

Answer (score 5):

[PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) can split a PDF into multiple pages:

```
pdftk filename.pdf burst
```

See the [manual](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-burst) and [examples](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) pages for more.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PDF Split and Merge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/).

Comment: +1, PDFsam is also my choice.

Comment: I use this regularly at work and it always does the trick, plus it is free.

Answer (score 1):

[jPDF Tweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/) can split PDFs into multiple files (if you know the owner password). It can also remove add/remove security restrictions (if you know the owner password) or show the user password if you know the owner password.

There are also (free) tools that can remove security without knowing the owner password, but since Adobe has good lawyers that sue everyone who provides (a link to) such a tool, you will most likely find them on Russian sites and not here...

The only legal option is to ask the copyright holder for the owner password, though.